# PHP session has wrong message

Tags: php, session, cookies, authentication

Does anyone know why this code gives false when it should give true?

```
setcookie("r", "", strtotime('2020-01-01'));
if (isset($_COOKIE["r"])) {
  echo "true";
}
else {
  echo "false";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php):

> Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the next page load with the $_COOKIE or $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS arrays.

Basically you can't access a cookie you just set since cookies are only sent with each page request. So it actually doesn't exist yet.

Comment: what do you mean by "they can be accessed on the next page load"?

Comment: The page needs to finish processing on the server side, send the content to the browser, and then a new request must be made.

Comment: Even when close the page and the browser and load them again I still get "false"!. How to know that the page has finished processing?

Comment: Try giving that cookie a value other then an empty string

Comment: Oh yes, it works now. So the problem is that the cookie was empty? One more question: Will this cookie still be in my computer when I restart it?

Comment: Yes. Unless you specifically do something to delete that cookie prematurely it will stay even if you reboot.

Comment: Thanks John Conde, great help.